# take a tab delimited file and update a MySQL field based on matching rows to a unique field

Tags: php, mysql, fgetcsv, delimited

Trying to piece together fgetcsv questions and answers to get where I need to be but do not grasp the basics enough to get the result I need.
The Tab delimited file sample....

```
╔══════════════╦════════════╦═══════╦══════════╗
║     sku      ║    asin    ║ price ║ quantity ║
╠══════════════╬════════════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║ 00-1IAB-H5E9 ║ B008S0TEFQ ║ 5.00  ║        1 ║
║ 00-BOXP-HDX4 ║ B00BP9N4JO ║ 20.00 ║        1 ║
╚══════════════╩════════════╩═══════╩══════════╝
```

I need to update the database with a new quantity, based on the sku.  Found a lot of similar answers, but not exactly what I need.  Price and ASIN are ignored.  Here is my code so far of the relevant portion.

```
$fin = fopen('qtyme.txt','r') or die('cant open file');
$link = mysql_connect('xxxx.com', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');
If (!$link) {
    die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
@mysql_select_db('xxxx') or die ('Unable to select database');
echo "Connection succeeded, starting processing..... <br />\n";
while (($data=fgetcsv($fin,r,"/t"))!==FALSE) {
    $query = "UPDATE products SET products_quantity = '".$data[3]."' WHERE products_sku = '".$data[0]."'";
    mysql_query($query);
    echo ($query) . "<br />\n";
    }
fclose($fin);
mysql_close();
```

Obviously I do not know what I am doing, but it appears my issue is in defining the columns to pull out the proper data for the UPDATE.

help?

FINAL Solution:  Thanks a lot ofr the help!

```
$link = mysql_connect('xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx'); If (!$link) {
    die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); } @mysql_select_db('xxxx') or die ('Unable to select database');

$sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE `tmpStock`"; mysql_query($sql); echo "Temporary Table Deleted...<br>";

$result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'qtyme.txt' INTO TABLE tmpStock FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'")or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ()); echo "Temporary Data Uploaded and Inserted...<br>";

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE products a INNER JOIN tmpStock b ON a.products_sku = b.sku SET a.products_quantity = b.quantity")or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ()); echo "All Quantity's Updated...";

mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: The problem appears to be the fgetcsv. You have a 2nd parameter of r when it should be the max line size (or 0 to default it), while the 3rd parameter has the wrong slash to be used with a t to denote a tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be tempted to create a temp table, load your delimited file into the temp table and then do a single update using a JOIN between your existing table and the temp table.

Something like this (not tested so please excuse any typos)

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
If (!$link) 
{
    die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
@mysql_select_db('testarea') or die ('Unable to select database');

echo "Connection succeeded, starting processing..... <br />\n";

$result = mysql_query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpStock
(sku varchar(50),
asin varchar(50),
price double(16,2),
quantity int(11),
KEY sku (sku )
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ");

$result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/wamp/www/TestArea/qtyme.txt' INTO TABLE tmpStock FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'")or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE products a INNER JOIN tmpStock b ON a.products_sku = b.sku SET a.products_quantity = b.quantity")or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());

?>
```

PS - probably should use mysqli, but I have stuck with mysql as that is what you are already using.

Comment: With what little I know I should have come up with that.  Brilliant solution.  Due to security restrictions I had to give up on a temp table, and just truncate it when done and leave it in place, no big deal.  Also had to add LOCAL to LOAD DATA for security reasons on the server.

Comment: Thank you, final code that got around a few minor security issues on the host server...